# EOFError Ran out of input Python

Tags: python, save, pickle

I am trying to use pickle to create a save file for my game, but When I try to submit my dictionary, and then take that information back, but it isn't working.

```
import pickle
data = {'health':100, 'gold':1560, 'name': 'mariano'}
with open('s.txt','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f, protocol = 2)

with open('s.txt','rb') as f:
    data = pickle.load(f)
```

then when I run that code it gives me this error

```
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Really, I still get an error

Comment: Works for me as well. What version of python are you using, and what OS are you on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong, or at least how I fixed the situation. You were trying to use a file that was already pickled, and since it ran with an error it broke it, all you have to do is change the name of the file.

Comment: +1 Can confirm, I just had a similar problem in my own code: I nested a shelf call within another call to the same shelf. Getting rid of the nesting solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue. My code looked like this:

```
h = open("my_file.pkl", "wb")
pickle.dump(my_data, h)
```

That was within a cell in a Jupyter notebook. When trying to load `my_file.pkl` later I'd get `EOFError: Ran out of input`.

I believe the cause of the error was the file handler `h` wasn't getting closed, meaning the file didn't save correctly. Changing it to this fixed the problem:

```
with open("my_file.pkl", "wb") as h:
    pickle.dump(my_data, h)
```