# EOFError: Ran out of input when trying to scrape data from wikipedia

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to scrape data off of wikipedia

```
if refresh:
    page = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farebox_recovery_ratio'
    wikitables = read_html(page)
    table = wikitables[1]
    pickle.dump(table, open(r"wiki_table.pkl", "wb"))
else:
    table = pickle.load(open(r"wiki_table.pkl", "rb"))
```

this is the error message I am getting on terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "judy.py", line 16, in <module>
    table = pickle.load(open(r"wiki_table.pkl", "rb"))
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

this code ran perfectly on my friend's laptop but wont run on mine. please help! :)

Comment: Without a [mcve], have you looked at other similar questions and their suggested solutions? such as [EOFError Ran out of input Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514494/eoferror-ran-out-of-input-python), and [many others](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=EOFError%3a%20Ran%20out%20of%20input)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure we can run your code, so we can verify and confirm the problem you are having, and test if we can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try to flush the input after the dump function call like this

```
if refresh:
    page = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farebox_recovery_ratio'
    wikitables = read_html(page)
    table = wikitables[1]
    with open(r"wiki_table.pkl", "wb") as result_file:
        pickle.dump(table, result_file)
        result_file.flush()
else:
    table = pickle.load(open(r"wiki_table.pkl", "rb"))
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It's still displaying the same error message unfortunately

Comment: that's odd, you regenerated the file before reading from it again, right?